# rails rake test, url helpers not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

Getting the following when running my capybara rails tests with "rake test".  Problem seems to be url helpers I'm using in my application.html.erb:

```
DashboardLoginTest#test_login_and_check_dashboard:
ActionView::Template::Error: arguments passed to url_for can't be handled. Please require routes or provide your own implementation
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:29:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__938277815294620636_4045700'
    test/integration/dashboard_login_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:DashboardLoginTest>'
```

Here's line 29 in application.html.erb that its complaining about:

```
      <%= link_to("asdf", root_path, {:class => 'brand'}) %>
```

Here's what the test looks like:

```
  test "login and check dashboard" do
    visit("/")
    assert page.has_content?("welcome")
  end
```

Here's my test_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'factory_girl'
require 'capybara/rails'

include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!

def main_app
  Rails.application.class.routes.url_helpers
end

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending!
  fixtures :all
end

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # Make the Capybara DSL available in all integration tests
  include Capybara::DSL
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def sign_in(user = nil)

    if user.nil?
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      $current_user = user
    end

    login_as(user, :scope => :user)
    user.confirmed_at = Time.now
    user.save

  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your `spec_helper.rb`?

Comment: I'm not using rspec.  Just ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest.  I added my test_helper.rb

Comment: Did you try `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` inside of the `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` class block?

Comment: updated question to include that line.  yes, same problem.

Comment: Josh Nankin, did you ever figure this out? Running into similar issues.